# Trying to install Ubuntu on Lenovo T61 laptop

Tags: windows, live-cd, dvd

I downloaded the Ubuntu file (Latest stable release) to a blank CD-R but got the error message that there was not enough room on the CD. One file got on the CD i think but more was supposed to be on it. So how big are the files going onto the CD from Ubuntu?

I tried downloading to DVD-R but that didn't work at all: it appears that the Sonic program I used was not capable of burning DVDs.

Why does the Ubuntu help topic on downloading sometimes say use a CD and other times a DVD?

The program I was using is the default on my laptop, Sonic. Should I use another program? Isn't there a default Windows program for burning CDs and DVDs?
How do I change the default program for the optical D: drive?

I used the Universal USB Installer for linux to make a CD but that did not work.
See comments below for details.

Windows XP SP3. Firefox.

Comment: You wrote, "I tried downloading to DVD-R but that didn't work at all" but that does not explain the point of failure. Were you unable to download the full DVD distro? Did you download it but it failed the MD5 checksum? Did you have a problem burning it to DVD-R? Or, did the first three steps go OK but you had an installation problem, and if so, where did it fail? Please be specific, and edit the original post by clicking on the grey 'edit' link above to revise the original question.

Comment: Also, this website, and the other Stack Exchange sites like the Windows stack Exchange site http://superuser.com/ , are dedicated to creating a large answerbase to help users. Therefore, we want to break problems down into chunks easily digested, and you're asking a lot of questions above. Other folks may edit your question into a series of individual questions, and tackle one chunk at a time. Don't let that confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

> So how big are the files going onto the CD from Ubuntu?

The full ubuntu-12.04.4-dvd-amd64.iso image of all the files is 1.6G in size.

> Why does the Ubuntu help topic on downloading sometimes say use a CD and other times a DVD?

Because some Ubuntu [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (AKA 'distro') will fit on a CD, whereas the full Ubuntu distro with Unity requires a DVD. There are many flavors of Ubuntu, briefly explained on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors). You've got a choice with Ubuntu of which Desktop Environment you want to use to manage your desktop, and once you choose the desktop, then you also choose the utility programs which work with it, and the 'libraries' of files which support it.

> Isn't there a default Windows program for burning CDs and DVDs?

Not with XP. The [Microsoft Forums](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/answers?tId=13e46e56-7084-446d-ae00-211e5b8fa811) recommend the free app [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), but the highest rated free app for Windows CD/DVD burning at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) is [cdrtfe](http://cdrtfe.sourceforge.net/cdrtfe/index_en.html).

To make what you burn bootable, you must burn it using the Mastered format, as the Live File System on a CD or DVD is not bootable. The Mastered format is explained at this [Windows Explorer for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-CD-or-DVD-in-Windows-Explorer) link.

> Should I use another program?

Since you're having problems with using a CD and DVD, perhaps you should use the [free app for Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) which lets you create a [LiveUSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) on a flash drive to install from.

There's a big advantage to the LiveUSB; freedom of choice. LiveUSBs lets you try one version, wipe it clean, and then try another, to seee which you like then best. Then, once you settle on your preference and actually install it to your hard drive, then you can customize it with wallpaper, fonts, cursor and other visual elements.

The LiveUSB also leaves your XP install intact, and you can access the data on the hard drive, and save files to the hard drive.

The [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) and [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org) versions are more similar to XP, IMHO, than Ubuntu with [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/about/), which uses a [more different desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28desktop_environment%29).

Comment: OK thanks for your replies. On the one hand I am trying to use the Linux OS to help diagnose audio problems on my T61. I want to see if the problems occur using Linux. On the other hand I have to move to a new OS soon, and am considering Linux and WIN7. This will be a chance to see what Linux is like. I'll try the USB tomorrow.

Comment: Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu all work dandy with my R60, SL400 and T500, FYI.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to install Kubuntu because when I got to the step of selecting the iso file, there was no iso file on the USB stick. I had already downloaded the installer from Pendrivelinux to the stick. I tried several times, followed directions, checked that my USB was formatted correctly, checked that there was enough room on the stick (7GB).

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer from someone about my problems with installing Kubuntu. What else can I do about this? Maybe go to another website for help I guess.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above that it was correctly formatted. The format was one of the items on the list to check.

Comment: Pendrive Linux is a website with nine different versions of flashdrive installers for creating LiveUSBs. Did you use Universal USB Installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/  or one of the other eight installers mentioned there? I suggest, if you didn't use it before, use the Universal USB Installer since it will automatically download the Kubuntu ISO and install it on your flashdrive.  Also, please click on the edit link askubuntu.com/posts/434380/edit and add the answer to your question, instead of replying in comments, so we can update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to burn the ISO onto a CD.  Had to use a DVD+R.  I burned my image using Windows 10 "burn ISO" function.  Worked perfectly.  Also I had to use the boot option - boot cd/dvd on my laptop to get the ISO to load.